# Having Issues Rendering api data in Material Angular Table

Tags: html, angular, typescript, api, angular-material

Good Afternoon,
I am trying to render the api data in a material table, but I am having issues connecting my NasaApiService to the dataSource array.
As of right now I am getting a "Type 'MatTableDataSource' is not assignable to type '[]'. error. Any help is much appreciated.

```js
/*Nasa Service*/

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface NasaStation {
  name: string;
  nametype: string;
  id: string;
  year: string;
  recclass: string;
  items: any;
}


@Injectable()
export class NasaApiService {
parsed: any;
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { 

  }
  getNasaData(): Observable<NasaStation> {
    return this._http.get<NasaStation>('https://data.nasa.gov/resource/gh4g-9sfh.json');
  }
}

/*nasa.component.*/

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NasaApiService} from '../nasa-api.service';
 import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatTable,MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

const api = 'https://data.nasa.gov/resource/gh4g-9sfh.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nasa',
  templateUrl: './nasa.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nasa.component.css']
})
export class NasaComponent implements OnInit {
 data;
dataSource: [];
displayedColumns: string[] = ['Name', 'Name-type', 'ID', 'Year', 'Recclass'];
 
  constructor(private _nasa: NasaApiService) { 
   
  }

  ngOnInit(){
  this._nasa.getNasaData().subscribe(data => {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
    this.data = data;
    console.log(data);
   
  })
  
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  ngOnInit(){
  this._nasa.getNasaData().subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data;
    this.dataSource = this.data;
    console.log(this.dataSource);
   
  })

  }


}
```

Was my final nasa.component code and I just passed datasource into Material Angular.